# Oracle SQL invalid argument

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I try to add another `MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 101, KARAKTER))` to this statement, but gives me invalid argument? What is the problem?

**This works and is the original query**

```
MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 47, KARAKTER)) AS SP1,
to_number(concat(concat(MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 141, KARAKTER)),
MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 161, KARAKTER))),MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 121, KARAKTER)))) AS SP2
```

**This doesn't work and is giving me an invalid argument error**

```
MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 47, KARAKTER)) AS SP1,
to_number(concat(concat(MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 141, KARAKTER)),
MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 161, KARAKTER))),
MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 121, KARAKTER))), MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 101, KARAKTER)) AS SP2
```

Comment: I think you also need another concat(...), something like this:  
concat(
 concat(
  concat(
   MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 141, KARAKTER)),
   MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 161, KARAKTER))
  ),
  MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 121, KARAKTER))
 ), MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 101, KARAKTER))
)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact error you get, and a full query. With just that snippet it seems to generate "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis", because of the missing `concat(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you added `MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 101, KARAKTER))` as a TO_NUMBER second parameter.

Your SP2 column definition before change looks like:

```
to_number(
    concat(
        concat(
            MAX( DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 141, KARAKTER) ),
            MAX( DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 161, KARAKTER) )
        ),
        MAX( DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 121, KARAKTER) )
    )
) AS SP2
```

You if you want to concat additional character you have to add third `CONCAT` execution like:

```
to_number(
    concat(
        concat(
            concat(
                MAX( DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 141, KARAKTER) ),
                MAX( DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 161, KARAKTER) )
            ),
            MAX( DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 121, KARAKTER) )
        ),
        MAX( DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 101, KARAKTER) )
    )
) AS SP2
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `concat()` call as already noted, but nesting those is awkward anyway and it's east to make mistakes, as you've seen.

It's simpler to use the concatenation operator:

```
MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 47, KARAKTER)) AS SP1,
to_number(
     MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 141, KARAKTER))
  || MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 161, KARAKTER))
  || MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 121, KARAKTER))
  || MAX(DECODE(SPØRGSMÅL_ID, 101, KARAKTER))
) AS SP2
```

Concatenating values into a string that you then pass into `to_number()` looks a bit odd anyway, but without seeing sample data it's hard to tell if this actually makes sense for whatever you're doing with the result. The column name `KARAKTER` suggests you might be building up a string of letters rather than digits - or at least, not all digits - which would then throw "ORA-01722: invalid number".